# faster version of rank between groups and then sort by both group and rank

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, numpy, rank

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["Foo", "Foo", "Baar", "Foo", "Baar", "Foo", "Baar", "Baar"], 
               "count_1":[5,10,12,15,20,25,30,35], 
               "count_2" :[100,150,100,25,250,300,400,500]})
```

I need to make sure all distinct groups (e.g., name here) with higher count_2 first. I currently rank between groups and then sort the data frame by both group and the rank to move the distinct group with higher ranks up.

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby("name")["count_2"].rank(method="max", ascending=False)
df = df.sort_values(by=["rank", "count_2"], ascending=[True, False])
df["final_rank"] = xrange(1,len(df)+1)
```

It produces the results I want, like this:

```
 count_1    count_2  name   rank   final_rank
   35        500     Baar    1      1
   25        300    Foo      1      2
   30        400    Baar     2      3
   10        150    Foo      2      4
   20        250    Baar     3      5
   5         100    Foo      3      6
   12        100    Baar     4      7
   15         25    Foo      4      8
```

However, this is relatively slow as I need to do it repeately on different datasets, and need it to be very fast, I am testing on a DF with 30 rows.

I am asking any other ways to improve the speed? The faster the better!

Many Thanks

Comment: A few thoughts on this:  (1) doing some quick timings on a larger sample dataframe, it appears approx 98% of your time is spent on the first ('groupby') line, (2) you didn't make any basic errors in what you did here as far as I can tell, (3) in the past, some groupby operations could be slow on big dataframes with large numbers of groups, (4) most groupby operations are pretty fast now ("cythonized") but if not, there are often workarounds

Comment: Overall, I would recommend making a new question with 2 changes:  (1) provide a larger dataframe for testing (perhaps use something like "`np.random.choice(range(x),size=y)`" -- your question is about speed on large data and hence can't be tested on your small sample dataframe (2) just focus on the groupby line since that is the slow part

Comment: @JohnE Thanks for the response. I changed my phrase a bit, one part of the calculation which needs to be very fast is on about a DF of 30 rows, I did %timeit on every command, it's the 'rank' function which takes the most of the time,  I haven't figured out a way to improve it yet.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm saying too, it's the `groupby/rank` line -- some groupby operations are much faster than others, it's the combo of `groupby` and a specific method (like `rank`) that can be slow in some situations.

Comment: I'm confused about the "30 rows" though.  You can't really optimize something like that as it's so fast to begin with and you can't optimize the basic overhead of method calls.  If the slowness involves repeated operations on small dataframes, what you might need to do is look into combining them into one or more larger dataframes.  Vectorization has little benefit (or perhaps even a net cost) on tiny dataframes.  The benefit is from dataframes with much more than 30 rows.

Comment: @JohnE it's a stream data, I had stream data of 30 rows, so i have to process it every time when it comes, but my processing time becomes at least doubled after I implemented this function. So I am looking for any other ways to do so.